# Help with booleans

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on booleans. However, the boolean modifier doesn't seem to be working as described in the tutorial.

This is the video in question:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8aw3bQoArg

He uses a union operation to create the desired holes. When I do this, it simply joins the objects without creating the same hole in the mesh. This is what I end up with. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The instructions in the video worked fine for me.  Could you maybe reproduce the problem from just after you add the Boolean modifier and switch it to Union, but before you apply it, and then post that as a .blend file (to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I attached the .blend file to my original post. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think I included the wrong blend file earlier. I updated my original post. It should have the blend file that includes the unapplied modifier.

Comment: I can confirm it works in 2.79, but not in 2.8 in that way. Modifier works for manifold objects. Tutorial use non-manifold object. See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html (BTW your blend has Solidify modifier applied before boolean.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Have they replaced it with a similar feature? If it worked in 2.79, why get rid of it unless it has been replaced by something better?

I'm not sure I fully understand the concept of what is manifold and non-manifold, unfortunately. I tried the boolean operation without the solidify modifier, but it didn't work. I'm at a loss, as I can't find any tutorials that explain how to do it in 2.8.

Answer (score 2):

Boolean modifier works for manifold objects. Tutorial from blender 2.7 use non-manifold object. For more see manual paragraph "Warning" https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html

Manual says to used manifold objects for modifier, but if you close topology of your mesh it will generates co-planar bottom faces that will run into another issue :)

So ... not recommended, but working in this case - apply boolean modifier (Union) on non-manifold mesh and delete unwanted faces (face select - Alt+Shift) ... after that use Solidify modifier.

[image]

Comment: I also came up with this solution of deleting faces, but is this the right way?

Comment: Thank you so much for the work around. I didn't realise those faces were available to me after union.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you might just cut a 45 degree miter from a central point using <kbd>K</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, an angle-constrained Knife, using either an array or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>90</kbd> duplications to rotate the sections into place.

[image]

... but maybe I'm just Boolean-phobic.

[image]